# Boost::multi_index with map

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-multi-index

I have a question about modifying elements in boost::multi_index container. 
What I have is the structure, containing some pre-defined parameters and 
a number of parameters, which are defined at run-time, and stored in a map. 
Here is a simplified version of the structure:

```
class Sdata{

    QMap<ParamName, Param> params; // parameters defined at run-time

public:

    int num;
    QString key;
    // more pre-defined parameters
    // methods to modify the map
    // as an example - mock version of a function to add the parameter
    // there are more functions operating on the QMAP<...>, which follow the same 
    // rule - return true if they operated successfully, false otherwise.
    bool add_param(ParamName name, Param value){
        if (params.contains(name)) return false;
        params.insert(name, value);
        return true;    
    }

};
```

Now, I want to iterate over different combinations of the **pre-defined** parameters 
of Sdata. To do this, I went for boost::multi_index:

```
typedef multi_index_container<Sdata,
indexed_by <
// by insertion order
    random_access<>,
//by key
    hashed_unique<
        tag<sdata_tags::byKey>,
        const_mem_fun<Sdata, SdataKey, &Sdata::get_key>
    >,
//by TS
    ordered_non_unique<
        tag<sdata_tags::byTS>,
        const_mem_fun<Sdata, TS, &Sdata::get_ts>
    >,

    /// more keys and composite-keys
>//end indexed by
> SdataDB;
```

And now, I want to access and modify the parameters inside the `QMap<...>`.

**Q1** Do I get it correctly that to modify any field (even those unrelated to 
the index), one needs to use functors and do something as below?

```
Sdatas_byKey const &l = sdatas.get<sdata_tags::byKey>();
auto it = l.find(key);
l.modify(it, Functor(...))
```

**Q2** How to get the result of the method using the functor? I.e., I have a functor:

```
struct SdataRemoveParam : public std::unary_function<Sdata, void>{
    ParamName name;
    SdataRemoveParam(ParamName h): name(h){}
    void operator ()(Sdata &sdata){
        sdata.remove_param (name); // this returns false if there is no param
    }
};
```

How to know if the remove_param returned `true` or `false` in this example:

```
Sdatas_byKey const &l = sdatas.get<sdata_tags::byKey>();
auto it = l.find(key);
l.modify(it, SdataRemoveParam("myname"));
```

What I've arrived to so far is to throw an exception, so that the `modify` 
method of boost::multi_index, when using with `Rollback` functor will return 
`false`:

```
struct SdataRemoveParam : public std::unary_function<Sdata, void>{
    ParamName name;
    SdataRemoveParam(ParamName h): name(h){}
    void operator ()(Sdata &sdata){
        if (!sdata.remove_param (name)) throw std::exception("Remove failed");
    }
};

// in some other place

Sdatas_byKey const &l = sdatas.get<sdata_tags::byKey>();
auto it = l.find(key);
bool res = l.modify(it, SdataRemoveParam("myname"), Rollback);
```

However, I do not like the decision, because it increases the risk of deleting 
the entry from the container.

**Q3** are there any better solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Q1** Do I get it correctly that to modify any field (even those
>   unrelated to the index), one needs to use functors and do something as
>   below?

Short answer is yes, use `modify` for safety. If you're absolutely sure that the data you modify does not belong to *any* index, then you can get by with an ugly cast:

```
const_cast<Sdata&>(*it).remove_param("myname");
```

but this is strongly discouraged. With C++11 (which you seem to be using), you can use lambdas rather than cumbersome user-defined functors:

```
Sdatas_byKey &l = sdatas.get<sdata_tags::byKey>(); // note, this can't be const
auto it = l.find(key);
l.modify(it, [](Sdata& s){
  s.remove_param("myname");
});
```

> **Q2** How to get the result of the method using the functor?

Again, with lambdas this is very simple:

```
bool res;
l.modify(it, [&](Sdata& s){
  res=s.remove_param("myname");
});
```

With functors you can do the same but it requires more boilerplate (basically, have `SdataRemoveParam` store a pointer to `res`).

The following is just for fun: if you're using C++14 you can encapsulate the whole idiom very tersely like this (C++11 would be slightly harder):

```
template<typename Index,typename Iterator,typename F>
auto modify_inner_result(Index& i,Iterator it,F f)
{
  decltype(f(std::declval<typename Index::value_type&>())) res;
  i.modify(it,[&](auto& x){res=f(x);});
  return res;
}
...
bool res=modify_inner_result(l,it, [&](Sdata& s){
  return s.remove_param("myname");
});
```

Comment: Thanks! You saved my evening)) This is exactly what I need.